# Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 fe80::d635:1dff:fe01:1232%2

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns

I have a Kubernetes cluster - version 1.24.3 - consisting of four ubuntu 20.04 servers. The only problem is I get constant warnings regarding "Nameserver limits were exceeded..."

[image]

The image above is to highlight that this is happening on each node and to an excessive amount. Each message consists of:

```
Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 fe80::d635:1dff:fe01:1232%2
```

I have checked and people seem to point to the `resolv.conf` file containing to many entries. However, no answer explains if it is safe to remove certain entries. It also states in the file not to edit it.

How do I get it so that the warnings stop?

**resolv.conf:**

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search broadband localdomain
```

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste into the body of the question. Pictures can not be searched, are often cut off and force the person trying to help to leave the question in order to see the pic.

Comment: The picture is there to highlight that it is happening to each node and at an excessive amount. The entire message is in the title. Unfortunately, there is no more to the message. I will highlight that in my question though.

Comment: Are the errors from the k8s pods or the nodes? Is the `resolv.conf` you have shown from the pods or the nodes? Finally, other  than this warning, is there an actual observable problem due to this?

Comment: I believe this is from the pods. The `resolv.conf` file shown above is from the nodes. but checking some of the pods `resolv.conf` file there are 4 entries. There is no observable problem caused by this, but I would prefer the warning not to be flooded but these warnings.